# Moodle File Upload errors: An error occured whilst communicating with the server

Tags: file-upload, http-headers, moodle

With some Uploads in Moodle (3.9) Uploads are not successful, mainly pdf.
The message that comes up is: "An error occured whilst communicating with the server".

not successful requests show
POST /course/dndupload.php undefined

successful requests show
POST /course/dndupload.php HTTP/1.1

When a pdf is reexported with libre office for example the same pdf can be uploaded without problems.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Is the LibreOffice pdf smaller? It could be PHP timing out.

https://docs.moodle.org/311/en/File_upload_size#Modifying_the_php.ini_file

What is the value for `max_execution_time` ? You can check the PHP values here -

Site administration > Server > PHP info

Also, try switching debug to developer level and see what the error message is.

Site administration > Development > Debugging

Debug messages = Developer

Display debug messages = checked

Although be cautious changing the debug level if its a production site. If you have access to the `config.php` file then you can specify a user.

```
// You can specify a comma separated list of user ids that that always see
// debug messages, this overrides the debug flag in $CFG->debug and $CFG->debugdisplay
// for these users only.
// $CFG->debugusers = '2';
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response, in the meantime a solution to the problem was found. On the server a measurement against log4j2-vulnerability has been implemented: https://support.f5.com/csp/article/K59329043#proc2. This caused the misbehaviour, the iRule has been removed, now it works again.